# How to choose which directory to be shown at the top of IntelliJ project window?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu9AJ.png)

My project window looked like the picture above and I liked it.

[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdWbU.png)

But now it shows EVERYTHING in my Desktop directory.

I want the project window to show only the files in "core" folder but I can't find out how to change the settings.

Comment: You didn't open the correct project. File > Open > select "core" will fix it

Comment: Thanks for your help but I've tried it many times and it didn't work. I also tried File > Close Project and then reopened the "core" directory, but it still didn't work...

Comment: Try deleting the `.idea` directory in Desktop, then try again. IntelliJ thinks Desktop is a project, and core is just a subproject.

Comment: There's no .idea folder in Desktop :( I just deleted the "core" folder and created a new project folder with the same content. Now the project window works properly but still cannot find out why it did not work with the existing directory. Thanks anyway!!!

Comment: Have you also checked hidden folders? Good that it works now though:)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the File Menu in the top-bar, select Open Folder... and select the project Folder you want to open.
If you want to create a new project click on new and follow the steps.

Comment: Thanks! However I tried reopening the project many times and it didn't work... So I just decided to delete this "core" folder and to create a completely new project folder with exact same content. Now the project window works properly. I still don't know why it did not work with the existing directory :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Desktop directory was opened and indexed in the IDE. To fix the problem you can try to do:

- File | Close Project.
- Close the IDE window.
- Delete all .iml files and the .idea directory from both `Desktop` and `core` folders.
- Re-import your project in IntelliJ as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_import_project_start .